# Django, remove initial space of a template value in a textarea

Tags: django

I am trying to put some text in a textarea using a template variable like this:

```
{% if action == 'edit' %}
    <form>
        <textarea style='width: 420px; height: 65px'>
                {{ post.text }}
        </textarea>
    </form>
{% endif %}
```

However, I notice that the text is displayed with some initial whitespace that I can't remove. I tried creating a filter to `.strip()` the text before showing to the user but to no avail. Although the text is stripped from whitespace it does display with some space characters before the first letter.

Is there a solution for this?

Comment: try not to put space in your code <textarea style='width: 420px; height: 65px'>{{ post.text }}</textarea>

Comment: you are right. Make it an answer so I can accept it! :)

Comment: finish post my answer and thank you

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try not to put space in your code

```
<textarea style='width: 420px; height: 65px'>{{ post.text }}</textarea>
```

Comment: This is magic(LOL), simple yet efficient.